# Regex character class range generator with certain characters excluded

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

While I was working on a personal project, I found I needed to exclude certain characters in a regex range. So I thought, why not implement a custom range exclusion check for greater efficiency, it'll only take 5 lines or so. 60+ lines later, I produced this:

`regex_supplement.py`:

```
"""Supplementary regex modifying methods."""

from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...

    From the itertools recipes.
    """
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def _offset_byte_char(char, offset):
    """Offset a single byte char"""
    return (ord(char) + offset).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')

def escape_byte_in_character_class(char):
    """Escapes characters as necessary within the character class."""
    return b'\\' + char if char in b'-]^' else char

def byte_range(startchar, endchar, excluded):
    """Returns a pattern matching characters in the range startchar-endchar.
    Characters in excluded are excluded from the range.
    """
    excluded = sorted(char for char in excluded if startchar <= char <= endchar)

    char_ranges = []
    if len(excluded) >= 1:
        first_exclude = excluded[0]
        if startchar != first_exclude:
            # Another possibility = + 1
            char_ranges.append(
                (startchar, _offset_byte_char(first_exclude, -1))
            )
        for start, end in pairwise(excluded):
            # Adjacent or equal
            if ord(end) - 1 <= ord(start):
                continue
            char_ranges.append(
                (_offset_byte_char(start, 1), _offset_byte_char(end, -1))
            )
        last_exclude = excluded[-1]
        if endchar != last_exclude:
            char_ranges.append(
                (_offset_byte_char(last_exclude, 1), endchar)
            )
    else:
        char_ranges = [(startchar, endchar)]

    char_output = b''
    escape = escape_byte_in_character_class
    for char_range in char_ranges:
        # Doesn't minimize all '-', but that quickly gets complicated.
        # (Whether '-' needs to be escaped within a regex range is context dependent.)
        # '^' has even more potential easy optimization.
        start, end = char_range
        if start == end:
            char_output += escape(start)
        elif ord(start) == ord(end) - 1:
            char_output += escape(start) + escape(end)
        else:
            char_output += escape(start) + b'-' + escape(end)
    return b'[' + char_output + b']'
```

`test_regex_supplement.py`:

```
"""Regex supplement tests"""

import regex_supplement as re_supp

def test_byte_regex_range_empty():
    """Test that empty exclusions do not affect the range"""
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'a', b'c', []) == b'[a-c]'

def test_byte_regex_range_exclusion_outside():
    """An exclusion outside of the regex range should have no effect."""
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'a', b'c', [b'e']) == b'[a-c]'

offset = re_supp._offset_byte_char

def compare_escaped_within_range(char):
    """Test that the character is escaped at the beginning of a range."""
    end = offset(char, 3)
    assert re_supp.byte_range(char, end, [end]) == b'[\\' + char + b'-' + offset(end, -1) + b']'

def test_byte_regex_range_escaped_rbrac():
    """Test that ']' is escaped"""
    compare_escaped_within_range(b']')

def test_byte_regex_range_escaped_hyphen():
    """Test that '-' is escaped"""
    compare_escaped_within_range(b'-')

def test_byte_regex_range_escaped_caret():
    """Test that '^' is escaped"""
    compare_escaped_within_range(b'^')

def test_byte_regex_range_standard_1():
    """Test that a standard range behaves as expected"""
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'a', b'g', [b'd']) == b'[a-ce-g]'

def test_byte_regex_range_standard_2():
    """Test that a standard range with multiple exclusions behaves as expected"""
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'a', b'k', [b'd', b'h']) == b'[a-ce-gi-k]'

def test_byte_regex_range_optimized_1():
    """Test that ranges of 1 char are optimized to single characters."""
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'a', b'c', [b'b']) == b'[ac]'

def test_byte_regex_range_optimized_2():
    """Test that multiple ranges of 1 chars are optimized to single characters."""
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'a', b'e', [b'b', b'd']) == b'[ace]'
```

This is only implemented for bytestrings, because that's what I needed for my project. I actually learned that Python regular expressions can handle bytestrings during this project. The tests are intended to be run by pytest. I was originally considering adding in an optimization for single character ranges, but I decided not to because it would lead to more complicated escape-handling code (and the possibility for subtle bugs like double-escaping `]`), and it wasn't needed for my purposes.

I'm mostly concerned with efficiency (mostly of the resultant regex, but also of the program) and accuracy-checking, but stylistic and readability improvements are also appreciated.

Also, in hindsight, I might have considered implementing a lookahead with an exclusion character check preceding the range, but my current approach does have the advantage of discarding excluded characters that are outside of the range, and requiring less escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
offset = re_supp._offset_byte_char

def compare_escaped_within_range(char):
    """Test that the character is escaped at the beginning of a range."""
    end = offset(char, 3)
    assert re_supp.byte_range(char, end, [end]) == b'[\\' + char + b'-' + offset(end, -1) + b']'
```

Two weird things going on here. First, your unit test depends on an internal implementation detail of `re_supp` (namely the `_offset_byte_char` method). Second, you're actually storing that method in a *global variable*, which makes your test not standalone. You couldn't extract just the `compare_escaped_within_range` test into a different test file, for example, unless you brought the global `offset` along with it. It would at least be more maintainable to say

```
def compare_escaped_within_range(char):
    """Test that the character is escaped at the beginning of a range."""
    offset = re_supp._offset_byte_char
    end = offset(char, 3)
    assert re_supp.byte_range(char, end, [end]) == b'[\\' + char + b'-' + offset(end, -1) + b']'
```

But it would be even better not to depend on that detail at all! Either make `_offset_byte_char` a public member of the API (lose the underscore), or just reimplement it yourself where you need it.

When you reimplement it, consider that Python offers the `chr` builtin to do exactly what you're currently doing with all that `byteorder='big'` nonsense on ints. Although I guess Python3 does force you to know about `latin_1` encoding:

```
offset = lambda x, y: chr(ord(x) + y).encode('latin_1')
```

---

IIUC, your public API really just consists of the function `byte_range(b, e, xs)`, where `b` and `e` are single bytes and `xs` is an iterable of bytes — which generates a regex character class matching any of the bytes in `b` to `e` inclusive, but excluding all of the bytes in `xs`.

In other words, it produces a regex which is the moral equivalent of `(?=[b-e])(?![xs]).`, or more succinctly `(?![xs])[b-e]`.

I guess you knew this, but it does feel like your 60-line thing is a bit overengineered. ;)

---

Personally I would write `ch` everywhere you wrote `char`, but that's probably partly due to my being primarily a C and C++ programmer. ;)  `ch` would still be shorter and arguably harder to confuse with `chr`, though...

---

Again on the testing side: your `compare_escaped_within_range` seems overdetermined and overcomplicated. If I were writing tests for your API, I would write one like this:

```
def test_inputs(b, e, xs):
    needle = re_supp.byte_range(b, e, xs)
    for i in range(256):
        haystack = chr(i).encode('latin_1')
        expected = (ord(b) <= i <= ord(e)) and (haystack not in xs)
        actual = bool(re.match(needle, haystack))
        assert actual == expected
```

And then I'd make sure all of my tests *at least* verified that `test_inputs(b, e, xs)` passed for their inputs. Even if they went on to verify other properties.

```
def test_byte_regex_range_escaped_caret():
    """Test that '^' is escaped"""
    test_inputs(b'^', b'a', [b'a'])
    assert re_supp.byte_range(b'^', b'a', [b'a']) == b'[\\^-`]')  # should we even verify this, or are we micromanaging?
```

Incidentally, you got very lucky that out of `]`, `^`, and `-`, no two of them are exactly 2 positions apart in the ASCII table! Did you know that? Do you expect your maintainer to know that `3` is a magic number in this respect — or should you maybe document it for posterity?

---

I ran my `test_inputs` on some random data and discovered some bugs in your code. Most blatantly, you forgot that `\` needs to be escaped. So `test_inputs(b'\\', b'A', [])` fails.

Fix the trivial bug by adding two characters in `escape_byte_in_character_class`. Now add a regression test: `compare_escaped_within_range(b'\\')`. The test still fails! Why? :)

And you don't handle the completely empty case: `test_inputs(b'A', b'A', [b'A'])` fails.

And you don't handle `test_inputs(b'B', b'A', [])` either, but that's more of an input validation issue, which is an issue of taste. Maybe you want to return `b'(?!.).'` in that case; maybe you want to assert-fail; or maybe you're happy just saying "don't do that."

The moral of the story is that you should always write a test harness that permits fuzzing! It's never wasted effort. ...Well, it's never *effort that fails to find bugs,* anyway. :)

Comment: Very useful answer all around! Regarding switching to `chr().encode('latin1')`, I feel like that's relying on an implementation detail of bytestrings that `latin1` happens to map to bytestrings perfectly. I guess that's unlikely to change, but I still feel it makes the code less clear. I think Python just has a rough edge by always requiring `byteorder` in `to_bytes`. For 1 byte conversions, there are no *bytes* to order, so it doesn't have relevance! And yes, my solution is admittedly over-engineered, but it does have *some* benefits, which I mentioned in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: I could have also done `bytes([i])` for the int to bytestring conversion, which might be the most succinct and best solution. I'm not arguing that what I've done with `offset` is good style (it's clearly bad style), but I'm not certain what you mean when say "You couldn't extract just the `compare_escaped_within_range` test into a different test file, for example, unless you brought the global `offset` along with it." If you extracted `compare_escaped_within_range`, it would keep the reference to the global `offset` within the original module, unless I misunderstand what you mean by "extract".